Shortest path in a graph where edge weights can vary dynamically based on the path taken
I have a directed acyclic graph whith negative edges where edge weights can vary dynamically based on the path taken.
E.g.:
There are 4 vertexes
A, B, C, D
I want to go from A to D
If I go on the route A->B->C->D, than the edge between C end D is 5.
If I go on the route A->C->D, than the edge between C and D is 3.

How can I find the shortest path in this graph to every vertex?
Can I use Bellman-Ford algorithm for this purpose?

Without further information on how edges update cost there are no efficient algorithms. Likely there are no efficient algorithms regardless for this problem, unless the cost update has a very specific form.
